# xamarin c# UiScrollingView not scrolling with a vertical list of buttons

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

i'm developing an ios app with xamarin and only c# code, without any designer.

I implemented a UiScrollView with a long list of buttons as follows:

```
var sizes = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;// 320, 480
....
scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(20, 200, sizes.Width - 40, sizes.Height - 200));
scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Magenta;

View.AddSubview(scrollView);
```

and then i added the list of buttons:

```
var m1 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    m1.Frame = new RectangleF(45, -50, 230, 20);
    m1.SetTitle("Beautiful That Way", UIControlState.Normal);
    m1.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => OpenPlayerView(PlayerOption.Stream, "mySongUrl.mp3", "Beautiful That Way" );

var m2 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    m2.Frame = new RectangleF(45, -20, 230, 20);
    m2.SetTitle("Boys In The Sky", UIControlState.Normal);
    m2.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => OpenPlayerView(PlayerOption.Stream, "mySongUrl.mp3", "Boys In The Sky");

var m3 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    m3.Frame = new RectangleF(45, 10, 230, 20);         m3.SetTitle("Cos'é l'Amor", UIControlState.Normal);
    m3.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => OpenPlayerView(PlayerOption.Stream, "mySongUrl.mp3", "Cos'é l'Amor");

var m4 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    m4.Frame = new RectangleF(45, 40, 230, 20);
    m4.SetTitle("Dancing Qeen", UIControlState.Normal);
    m4.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => OpenPlayerView(PlayerOption.Stream, "mySongUrl.mp3", "Dancing Qeen");

var m5 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    m5.Frame = new RectangleF(45, 70, 230, 20);
    m5.SetTitle("Free", UIControlState.Normal);
    m5.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => OpenPlayerView(PlayerOption.Stream, "mySongUrl.mp3", "Free");

        scrollView.AddSubview(m1);
        scrollView.AddSubview(m2);
        scrollView.AddSubview(m3);
        scrollView.AddSubview(m4);
        scrollView.AddSubview(m5);
```

I need to add up to 60 buttons, and the UiScrollView does not scrolls...

Any idea how to solve?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try setting `AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the scroll view the size of the content within it, something like:

```
scrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 50 * 40);
```

#### Example:

```
scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
    button.Frame = new CGRect(40, 20 + (i * 40), 100, 40);
    button.SetTitle("Button : " + i, UIControlState.Normal);
    scrollView.Add(button);
}
scrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 50 * 40);
Add(scrollView);
```